# Send user info metadata to remote users with agora.io?

Tags: flutter, agora.io, clubhouse

I am using agora.io to create application like clubhouse with Flutter.
I was able to create and join room with room id and token created by custom nodejs-token server. But I'm stuck as all the data about user I can get with **userJoined** is his -

```
userJoined: (uid, elapsed) {
      log('userJoined $uid $elapsed');
      this.setState(() {
        remoteUid = uid;
      });
```

How can send user info like Firebase uid, profile photo etc. from currently joined user(also a logged in user) to other remote users in the room.

Answer (score 0):

To send other data, you will need to use the `agora_rtm` package paired with the video call. Take a look at this article to get started with RTM https://www.agora.io/en/blog/real-time-messaging-and-video-with-dynamic-channels-using-the-agora-flutter-sdk/